# Is "hardwork" a valid word?

Tags: is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

I came across this word in an English test, where "hardwork" was marked as the 'correct' answer for a question. I know of the adjective hardworking, but I thought "hardwork" was always written as two words, like "hard work".

An online search for "hardwork" reveals some results, but most of them seem to use the two-word version ("hard work"). [This page](https://www.definitions.net/definition/hardwork) on Definitions.net is the only dictionary I found mentioning "hardwork" as a single word. Is that a valid alternate spelling, and if so, where/when has it been used in the past?

Comment: What was the question to which "hardwork" was supposedly the correct answer?

Comment: It was a multiple-choice fill-in-the-blank question, along the lines of "This story will teach your child to give importance to ___ over shortcuts. Options: drudgery, duty, hardwork, burden. Perhaps it was just a typo (although it did derail me from finding the right answer!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED has no entry for single-word 'hardwork'.

[image: OED search results for single-word hardwork, showing zero results]

Your example on definitions.net was user-submitted, and in fact the provided citation doesn't use single-word 'hardwork'. Insofar as anything is "not a word", I'd say 'hardwork' counts.

Comment: I suppose that's as good an answer as any :)